# Need to remove pixel value from the image element

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I need to remove the pixel value from the image element by using the XSLT,

My Input xml is:

```
<img src="https://google.com/Service/Get/Content/images-v1/Images/savings-277.250x250.jpg" />
```

XSL I Used as:

```
<xsl:template match="img">
<xsl:element name="image">
<xsl:if test="@src">
<xsl:attribute name="href">
<xsl:value-of select="tokenize(@src, '/')[position() = last() - 2 or position() = last()]" separator="_"/>
</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Output I'm getting like:

```
<image href="images-v1_savings-277.250x250.jpg"/>
```

But i want to remove the pixel value (250x250) from the output:

```
<image href="images-v1_savings-277.jpg"/>
```

Please suggest some possible coding for this. I'm using XSLT version as 2.0 and saxon as saxon-PE 9.6.0.7. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use following code

```xsl
<xsl:template match="img">
  <xsl:element name="image">
    <xsl:if test="@src">
      <xsl:attribute name="href">
        <xsl:variable name="ajeet">
          <xsl:value-of select="tokenize(@src, '/')[position() = last() - 2 or position() = last()]" separator="_"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="replace($ajeet, '.([0-9]+)x([0-9]+)', '')"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```